# Html alt text in explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

Hi i my problem is alt text in explorer. In chrome alt text is showed immmediately and in explorer is showed after ~3s. Is any way how to display this text immediately? tanks

Comment: This is default browser behavior. Not much you can do about it.  Are you sure you want to use alt, though?   alt should be 'alternative' text for those who can't see images.

Comment: thanks this answer is enought for me.

Comment: @user3355351 The only way to have an absolutely consistent experience between all major browsers is to use JavaScript to show your own custom tooltip/alt text.